# Define overlap elements or elements not contained in subsets

Tags: algorithm, optimization, set, subset

I would like to check which strategy would be the most efficient to compute the problem described below

I have one set Q and two subsets L and R. I have three cases.

1) L ∩ R != 0. In this case, I want to get the array of overlapped elements. In the example below, the resultant set would be R = {4, 5}.

```
  Q = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
  L = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, *, *, *, *}
  R = {*, *, *, *, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

2) L ∩ R = 0. In this case, I want to get Q \ (L ∪ R). In the example below, the resultant set would be R = {4, 5, 6}.

```
  Q = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
  L = {0, 1, 2, 3, *, *, *, *, *, *}
  R = {*, *, *, *, *, *, *, 7, 8, 9}
```

3) Q \ (L ∪ R) = 0. In this case, I want to get the index where they find each other. In the example below, the index would be 4.

```
  Q = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
  L = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, *, *, *, *, *}
  R = {*, *, *, *, *, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking how to write union, intersect, and except functions for lists? You can probably look that up.

Comment: Solving the problem is not the problem. That can be solved with some loops. I want to know if someone knows an optimized way to compute that without multiple loops.

Comment: Then you should edit your question and add that. It's kind of hard to answer a question that you don't ask. You might consider, though, that you have to visit every element in each list at least once. So either you have to write loops to do that, or you call runtime library functions that contain loops. You're not going to get around that.

Comment: How do you define "the index where they find each other" if `Q=[0,1,2,3,4,5]`, `L=[0,*,2,*,4,*]` and `R=[*,1,*,3,*,5]`?

Comment: L and R are always uniform. You don't have empty spaces in between elements. I was thinking here. I think with dictionary is the best. As I said, if I get elements with 3, I have the first case; if I get elements with 1, I have the second case. If L or R are not empty and I get all elements with 2, I get the third case. Then the index is L.size() -1. Can you add an answer like that saying to use map/dictionary? I can mark it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not confident that the question as written, even with your additions in the comments, defines the entire problem. I'm not willing to provide an answer when I don't fully understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `L ∩ R != 0`, then I would:

Choose the two smallest arrays, and compare them to find the common elements.

This will save you a loop, and it will result in O(n<sup>2</sup>), instead of the naive O(n<sup>3</sup>).

In the other case, I don't see how you would avoid visiting every element of every array.

---

Note: If you would use a data structure, sush a hash map, then both cases would be soled in linear time.

Comment: But if you use a dictionary or hash map, both problems become O(n).

Comment: Yes @JimMischel, if this is acceptable by the OP, I agree!

Comment: If you add Q, L and R in a dictionary/map<string, int>, when you get the element.value == 3, you have the overlapped ones. When you have a element.value == 1 you get the difference. However, if you have the case that half of the set is contained in the L and half in the R, all element.counter will be equal to 2. How to get the index where they meet each other? I will add one more case.